# structure to use jQuery as a function and as a method?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm writing my first jQuery plugin based on [this documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Plugin_Methods) and I have a question about it. This particular example show you to how use jQuery as a method with an element, such as:

```
$("myelement").myfunction({title: blah});
```

However, how can I use it as a standalone function, without an element? Example:

```
$.myfunction({title: blah});
```

When I do this at the moment I get "$.myfunction is not a function"

Thanks!

Edit: current code:

```
(function( $ ){
  $.fn.tasks = function( options ) {

    var defaults = {
        'action'    : 'gettasks',
        'list'      : 'default',
        'task'      : '',
        'title'     : ''
    };

    var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options); 

    return this.each(function() {

        var $this = $(this);
        var ajax_load = "<img class='loading' src='images/ajax-loader.gif' alt='loading...' />";
        var urlparams;

        if ( options.action == 'gettasks' ) {
            urlparams = "action=gettasks";
            urlparams += "&list="+options.list;
        }

        if ( options.action == 'getlists' ) {
            urlparams = "action=getlists";
        }

        if ( options.action == 'create' ) {
            urlparams = "action=create&list="+options.list+"&title="+options.title;
        }

        if ( options.action == 'update' ) {
            urlparams = "action=update&list="+options.list+"&taskid="+options.task;
        }


        $.ajax({
            url: "include/tasks_handler.php?"+urlparams,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $this.html(ajax_load);
            },
            success: function(html){
                $this.html(html);
                if ( options.action == 'update' ) {
                    $("#taskList").tasks();
                }
            }
         });

    });
  };
})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define it as a function like this

```
$.myfunction = function(options){
   //method logic here
};

//Use it here
$.myfunction({title: blah});
```

However this way you cannot use `jQuery` chaining until and unless you return a `jQuery` object from this method.

Answer (score 1):

Add your function to the `jQuery` object itself, not to `jQuery.fn`.

e.g.

```
$.myfunction = function() { ... };
```

Comment: How can I make it work on both DOM and standalone? I've added my example code to the question.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers posted here showing you how to do each way, an important distinction to make here is: should you use `$` namespace or `$.fn` namespace?

If you see jQuery's internal methods, they make the following distinction.

- `$.fn` is used to operate on DOM elements
- `$` is used to operate on objects (arrays, collections, POJO etc.), having no knowledge of DOM's existence.

Comment: I understand, that's why I want to make it work in both ways, as I sometimes use it in DOM and sometimes standalone, they are not mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Yep. Just do it like this:

```
$.pluginName = function(/* arguments here */) {
   // Plugin Code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define it like this:

```
jQuery.myfunction = function(options) {
    alert(options.title);
};
```

and invoke like this:

```
$.myfunction({title: 'foo bar'});
```